# How to pause execution but keep other parts of a script running?

Tags: powershell, wait

Currently using the below but want to update this to wait 5 min before canceling the downtime without pausing the script.

What is the best way to go about this?

```
Write-Host "Removing Downtime After Five Minutes..." -ForegroundColor Green
Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
Remove-Downtime -APIKey $APIKey -AppKey $AppKey -Scope "stack:$StackLower" | Out-Null
```

No functions have been tested as of yet.

Comment: Are you asking how to make that code into a function, or make that code run in the background? Maybe start here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/09-functions - or update your question with more detail

Comment: I want to be able to set the removal of the downtime to 5 minutes and the script to continue on during that countdown.

Comment: Just wrap what you posted in a function block. If you are developing use the PS ISE to VSCode, there are built-in code snippets to give you a template to start with. Search for PowerShell ISE snippets or VSCode PowerShell snippets; then of course there are samples in the PS help files ```Get-Help -Name about_functions -detail```  and tons all over the web and on Youtube. A quick search for ***PS functions  -wait*** should give you your launch points.

Comment: What i am struggling with is I need to remove the downtime after five minutes but for the script to continue on while that 5 minutes is counting down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of options.

One would be to run the rest of the script as a job

```
$Now = (get-date)

Start-Job {#Other stuff
    # Rest of script goes here
    # to continue running in parallel
} -Name 'Other things to run'

Write-Host "$($Now.ToString("HH:mm")) - Removing Downtime After Five Minutes..." -ForegroundColor Green
Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
Remove-Downtime -APIKey $APIKey -AppKey $AppKey -Scope "stack:$StackLower" | Out-Null

Get-Job | Wait-Job | Remove-Job
```

alternatively...

```
$Now = get-date
Write-Host "$($Now.ToString("HH:mm")) - Removing Downtime After Five Minutes..." -ForegroundColor Green

Start-Job {#Remove Downtime
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
    Remove-Downtime -APIKey $APIKey -AppKey $AppKey -Scope "stack:$StackLower" | Out-Null
} -Name 'Remove Downtime'

# Rest of script goes here
# to continue running in parallel

Get-Job | Wait-Job | Remove-Job
```

Or use another PowerShell session to show the message.

```
$scriptblock = {
    $Now = get-date
    Write-Host "$($Now.ToString("HH:mm")) - Removing Downtime After Five Minutes..." -ForegroundColor Green
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
    Remove-Downtime -APIKey $APIKey -AppKey $AppKey -Scope "stack:$StackLower" | Out-Null
}

cmd /c start PowerShell -Command $scriptblock

# Rest of script goes here
# to continue running in parallel
```

You could also opt for the advanced option and using Winforms for the message to keep it cleaner.

```
$scriptblock = {# Only a bare minimum of properties used
    $Now = Get-Date

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    $form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.Text = "$($Now.ToString("HH:mm")) - Wait for me"
    $form.MaximizeBox = $False
    $form.MinimizeBox = $False
    $form.ControlBox = $False

    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Location = '10,10'
    $label.Width = $form.Width - 20
    $label.Text = 'Removing Downtime After Five Minutes...'

    $form.Controls.Add($label)
    $form.Show()
    $form.WindowState = 'Normal'
    $form.TopMost = $true
    $form.Activate()

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 300

    $form.Dispose()

    Remove-Downtime -APIKey $APIKey -AppKey $AppKey -Scope "stack:$StackLower" | Out-Null
}

cmd /c start /min PowerShell -Command $scriptblock

# Rest of script goes here
# to continue running in parallel
```

Comment: This is helpful but my issue here is the rest of the script does not continue while sleep counts down. There are actions that come after the bit I have provided that need to execute during this time. Is there a way to specify and expiration using something like now() and the expiration time?

Comment: This will make your code run in parallel. Did you try your code using any of the examples provided?

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get this working. Sorry for the late response and appreciate the insight.